# Is it good to use both TransactionScope and UnitOfWork in a single transaction process in C#?

Tags: c#, transactions, asp.net-core-3.1, unit-of-work

I have the following code where I am using TransactionScope and UnitOfWork pattern which is developed using asp.net core 3.1 and C#.

```
publc void TestMethod()
{
    var dto = _mapper.Map<Disclaimers>(request);
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        dto.CreatedBy = "Test1";
        dto.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        dto.UpdatedBy = "Test2";
        dto.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        await _testRepository.AddAsync(dto);
        await _testRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync();
        response.IsSuccessful = true;
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

I wanted to know is it ok or good practice to leverage both TransactionScope and UnitOfWork in the same method.

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As msdn docs says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute
> SaveChanges() to insert, update or delete on the database the
> framework will wrap that operation in a transaction.

If you have just one `SaveChanges` and one `DbContext`, then there is no need to use `TransactionScope`

Comment: Thanks @StepUp for your response.  How about a scenario where we have Insert into one table and update in another table.  Should we use Transactionscope and UnitOfWork together

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro If you call `SaveChanges` just one time and you have just one `DbContext`, then there is no need to use TransactionScope

Comment: Thanks much @StepUp for your response. It helped me a lot to understand the issue :)